# c++ Динамические массивы и их передача в функции

Tags: c++, массивы, ubuntu

написал функцию push_back_();

она не работает я не знаю почему.

**помогите пожалуйста**

вот код:

```
//includes
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

//namespaces
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

//defines
#define RETURN return 0

//prototypes
void FillArray(int* const arr,const int size);
void PrintArray(const int* const arr,const int size);
void CopyArray(const int* const Arr_From,int* Arr_To,const int size);
void push_back_(int *&arr,int* size,int value);

//main
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"ru"); //locale
    const auto _BEFORE_ = high_resolution_clock::now(); //start timer (for time account)
    srand(time(0));

    int size = 10; //size array
    int* array_ = new int[size]; //dinamic array

    FillArray(array_,size); //generation array
    PrintArray(array_,size); //print

    push_back_(array_,&size,3); //add element
    PrintArray(array_,size); //print

    delete[]array_; //clean memory

    //time account
    const auto _AFTER_ = high_resolution_clock::now();
    const float TIME_FOR_PROGRAM = duration_cast<milliseconds>(_AFTER_-_BEFORE_).count();
    cout<<"\n\n Programm completed in "<<TIME_FOR_PROGRAM<<"ms"<<endl;
    RETURN;
}

//Functions

void FillArray(int* const arr,const int size) {

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 30 + 1;
    }
}
void PrintArray(const int* const arr,const int size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout<<"\033[1;34m"<<arr[i]<<"\033[0m\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
void CopyArray(const int* const Arr_From,int* Arr_To,const int size) {
    delete[] Arr_To;
    Arr_To = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0;i < size;i++) {
        Arr_To[i] = Arr_From[i];
    }
}

void push_back_(int *&arr,int* size,int const value) {
    int* arr_cp = new int[*size+1];
    CopyArray(arr,arr_cp,*size);
    (*size)++;
    arr_cp[(*size)-1] = value;  
    CopyArray(arr_cp,arr,*size);
    delete[] arr_cp;

}
```

Вот ошибка:

[image: выполнение программы]

Comment: p.s. мне надо чтобы адрес массива остался прежнем.

Comment: Так не бывает. Новое выделение памяти вернет *какой-то* адрес. Может старый, может новый. Никакого "остался прежним" вам никто гарантировать не будет. В функции `CopyArray` написана чушь. Из-за нее и получается "double free".

Comment: ну если ее вызывать просто из main() то она прекрасно работает(

Comment: Функция `CopyArray` выполняет **две** задачи. Это очень не культурно. Уберите функцию удаления `delete[] Arr_To;`. Или если вам так удобно, то переименуйте функцию на : `FreeDestinationMakeNewAndCopyTo`.

Comment: @Lofectr: Вам показалось, что "она прекрасно работает". Плохо тестировали.

Comment: В функции `push_back_` : `[*size+1]` - очень расплывчатая операция. Приоритет между звёздочкой и плюсом одинаков. Может получиться, что вы получите значение не из того адреса : `[*(size+1)]`. Значит надо так : `[(*size)+1]`.

Comment: CopyArray работает как надо, она очищает массив на случай если размер массива№1 не совпадает с массивом№2, а как решить проблему с push_back_ я разобрался